# Is there a way to combine or concatenate the queues for Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007, powershell

Say I use Get-Queue -Server HT1 to pull up the queue on server transport1. It outputs something like this:

```
Identity       DeliveryType Status MessageCount NextHopDomain   
--------       ------------ ------ ------------ -------------   
HT1\47782      MapiDelivery Ready  0            mail1.c...
HT1\47783      MapiDelivery Ready  2            mail4.c....
HT1\48599      MapiDelivery Ready  0            mail2.c...
HT2\Submission Undefined    Ready  4            Submission    
HT2\47782      MapiDelivery Ready  0            mail1.c...
HT2\47783      MapiDelivery Ready  1            mail4.c....
HT3\48599      MapiDelivery Ready  0            mail2.c...
HT3\Submission Undefined    Ready  4            Submission
```

Is there a way to implement a loop or some logic so that I can get a cleaner one line output with a total queue count, even if I was to get the queue status on all transport server, something like this:

```
Server Queue

HT1      2
HT2      0
HT2      20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Get-Queue | Group-Object {$_.Identity.Server} | Select-Object Name,@{n="MessageCount";e={($_.group | Measure-Object MessageCount -sum).sum}}
```

Comment: +1, but you need to change $. to $_.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Gives me a nice and simple display now!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, you could apply a filter, such as

get-queue -server HT1 -Filter {MessageCount -gt 5}

this would only display results with messages greater than 5 in domain hop.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me closer to what I'm looking for but sometimes a couple of the queues are backed up, in which case there would still be 2 or more lines for it.